# Changing the solver parameters in Caffe through pycaffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

How can I change the solver parameter in Caffe through pycaffe?

E.g. right after calling `solver = caffe.get_solver(solver_prototxt_filename)` I would like to change the solver's parameters (learning rate, stepsize, gamma, momentum, base_lr, power, etc.), without having to change `solver_prototxt_filename`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can create a temporary file.

First of all, load your solver parameters with

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format
solver_config = caffe_pb2.SolverParameter()
with open('/your/solver/path') as f:
    text_format.Merge(str(f.read()), solver_config)
```

You can modify any solver parameter just setting the desired value in `solver_config` (e.g. `solver_config.test_interval = 15`). Then, it's just creating a temp file and load your solver from it:

```
new_solver_config = text_format.MessageToString(solver_config)
with open('temp.prototxt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_solver_config) 
solver = caffe.get_solver('temp.prototxt')
solver.step(1)
```

Comment: How can I modify repeated parameter e.g. _stepvalue_ in `solver_config` then? When I try to assign `solver_config.stepvalue = 1000` I got **AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to repeated field "stepvalue" in protocol message object.**

Comment: @TuBui cuz you are not using 'multistep' policy.